# SQLite in iOS behave strangely

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am new in iOS development and recently I am facing some strange behavior on iOS SQLite. I have an application that allow user to insert record into the SQLite DB. The application work fine but after sometime the record created by the user somehow disappear by itself. When this happen, subsequently when I try to create a new record it does not store the record in DB. The insert statement executed without error but data is not insert. Below is the function that perform the record insert logic. Please help, thank you.

```
+ (BOOL)insertAutoRecord:(AutoRecord *)record{
  BOOL ret = NO;

  NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@) values ('%@', %d, %d, '%@', %d, %d, %d)",
                   TABLE_NAME_AUTOMATIC_RECORDS,
                   COL_NAME_AUTO_RECORD_SENSOR_ID,
                   COL_NAME_AUTO_RECORD_MONITOR_START_DATE,
                   COL_NAME_AUTO_RECORD_MONITOR_END_DATE, 
                   COL_NAME_AUTO_RECORD_FREE_TEXT,
                   COL_NAME_AUTO_RECORD_CREATE_DATE,
                   COL_NAME_AUTO_RECORD_KID_ID,
                   COL_NAME_AUTO_RECORD_LAST_SYNC_DATE,
                   record.sensorId,
                   record.startDate,
                   record.endDate,
                   [record.freeText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"],
                   record.createDate,
                   record.kidId,
                   0];

 KSDelegate *appDelegate = (KSDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 sqlite3 *dbHandler = appDelegate.dbHandler;

 sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
 const char *insert_stmt = [query UTF8String];

 sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbHandler, insert_stmt, -1, &stmt, NULL);
 if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
 {
    ret = YES;
 }
 else
 {
    ret = NO;
 }
 sqlite3_finalize(stmt);


 if(ret == NO)
    return NO;

 query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select last_insert_rowid()"];

 if(sqlite3_prepare(dbHandler, [query UTF8String], -1, &stmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK)
    return NO;

 if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
 {
    int recordId = (int)sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    record.recordId = recordId;
 }
 else
    ret = NO;

 sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

 return ret;
}
```

Comment: Silly question, but are you copying the database to the Documents folder and opening that one? On your code above, I'll defer to others as I use the [FMDB] (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) Objective C wrapper that insulates me from the sqlite3 calls.

Comment: Dear Robert, the KSDelegate class will create the database in the Document folder when the application start. It will check if the table is not exist then I will create the table. The application allow the user to create other table records but not the record mentioned in the code above.

Here is the database path defined in one of my header file.
#define DATABASE_PATH [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"local_db.sqlite"]

Comment: In the KSDelegate class under the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, it will open and initialize the database

sqlite3_open([DATABASE_PATH UTF8String], &dbHandler);
[self initDatabase]; // this initDatabase will create the table if not exist.

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering if your database was being wiped as you built the app. When I heard you suggest that you see that the record existed, and then it magically disappears, it just smells like the database is getting wiped somehow. That was the only idea that leapt to mind for me.

Comment: Dear Robert, I also didn't specify clearly. The situation it that when I just start using the application everything work fine, then might be after few hours or days I bring the application up again, the record from the specified table defined in the constant TABLE_NAME_AUTOMATIC_RECORDS disappeared. After that when i call the  insertAutoRecord method, it run without error but data is not insert into the database. That is what it confused me. Any suggestion?

Comment: One additional thing is that if I uninstall and reinstall it, it is working fine for sometime until the same situation happen again. :(

Comment: No clue. That makes no sense. I (and many other) have complicated databases without any of this strange behavior you describe. Data just doesn't disappear from databases. The only things that can blow away data are delete/truncate statements, drop/create statements, or accidentally deleting/recreating the DB file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here the perfect example and sample code of SQlite..I suggest you to go through it...

[SQlite tutorial for iOS Developer](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)